# how to set a value for the listwidget item?

Tags: qt, qlistview, qlistwidget

I create A list widget in which I add items...my items are the filenames. Is any way to store the filepaths of this filenames? I want to know how to set a specific value to an item in the listwidget?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ListWidgetItem::setData(int role,Qvariant data);
```

to store your `filePath;`

like this:

```
QString fileName = "hello.txt";
QString filePath = "/home/user/hello.txt";

//Adding to listWidget
QListWidgetItem *item =new QListWidgetItem();

item->setText(fileName);
item->setData(1,filePath);//here role is set as 1

listWidget->addItem(item);
```

```
//For taking back that filePath

QString filePath =   listWidget->currentItem()->data(1); //note::: role equals 1
```

Comment: This works, but note that role of 1 is the Qt.DecorationRole enum and seems to tab the text in the list item. if  you use 256 its Qt.UserRole which doesn't seem to affect the text.